# Dart - not specifying a type?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I was wondering, if I run this code:

```
incrementionFunc(num1, num2) {
  print(num1+num2);
}

void main() {
  incrementionFunc(2.3,3);
}
```

I get no issues, and it prints out `5.3`. What's the difference between not specifying the type for the variables `num1, num2`, and writing out `var` for example (`var num1, var num2`)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type is `dynamic` if you don't specify it

meaning that this will compile but you'll get a runtime error:

```dart
void main() {
  incrementionFunc(2.3, '1');
}
```

As for `var`, placing it in method signature is redundant since it's the default as well.

As such, this will compile and won't throw an error:

```dart
incrementionFunc(var num1, num2) {
  num1 = 12;
  num2 = 13;
  print(num1+num2);
}


void main() {
  incrementionFunc(2.3, "1");
}
```

You will get different behavior if you replace `var` with `final`:

```dart
incrementionFunc(final num1, num2) {
  num1 = 12; // Compilation error: The final variable 'num1' can only be set once.
  num2 = 13;
  print(num1+num2);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between that and using `var` though?

Comment: `var` tries to *infer* the type if it can.  It's not possible to infer types for function parameters.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin, is it good practice to let var infer the type, or should you specify it as much as possible?

Comment: it all depends on your team/project's practices, in my team, we never specify variable types. We do, however, always specify method return type so we don't have any `dynamic` variables in the code. As for `final` vs `var` - use `final` if you won't assign a new value to a variable.